# What does the PROT_EXEC flag do in mprotect?

Tags: c++, c, linux

From this page: http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect

I understand the flags except for PROT_EXEC. What is the effect of calling

```
mprotect(ptr, size, PROT_EXEC);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual page you link to:

> **PROT_EXEC**
>
> The memory can be executed.

It marks the memory as executable, meaning it can contain code you can call and run.

Comment: So it has to do with functions? Please elaborate.

Comment: It's not at all obvious what that means. For example, how is execute code different from when reading or writing that address? You need to execute code to do all those things, so whats the difference?

Comment: @AnonymousEntity `PROT_EXEC` means that the ***memory itself*** can contain code. If you examine the memory map of your process, the memory containing the code for the program is marked `PROT_EXEC`, otherwise the code could not be executed. By using `mprotect` and the `PROT_EXEC` flag for some totally unrelated memory means you can dynamically allocate a page of memory, copy some arbitrary code into the memory, and then execute it like it was part of your program.